# How do I avoid changing a file's Linux permissions when saving over a samba connection?

Tags: linux, vim, network-shares, samba, gvim

I have an Ubuntu development server and a Windows 7 workstation. I use Windows Gvim to edit files on the linux server, over a samba connection.

Saving files from Windows change the Linux permissions in weird way depending on the Windows app I'm using and also depending on whether there's a file extension or not.

**Here are some tests**

No extension; Notepad2: 644 to 764

```
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 matt matt 0 2011-05-28 07:09 testfile
--- Save from Windows Notepad2 over network ---
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile
-rwxrw-r-- 1 matt matt 1 2011-05-28 07:09 testfile
```

No extension; Gvim: 644 to 760

```
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 matt matt 0 2011-05-28 07:10 testfile
--- Save from Windows Gvim over network ---
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile
-rwxrw---- 1 matt matt 0 2011-05-28 07:11 testfile
```

Extension; Notepad2: 644 to 644 (good!)

```
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 matt matt 0 2011-05-28 07:13 testfile.txt
--- Save from Windows Notepad2 over network ---
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 matt matt 0 2011-05-28 07:13 testfile.txt
```

Extension; Gvim: 644 to 760

```
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 matt matt 0 2011-05-28 07:14 testfile.txt
--- Save from Windows Gvim over network ---
matt@mattserver ~ % ls -l testfile.txt
-rwxrw---- 1 matt matt 0 2011-05-28 07:14 testfile.txt
```

**Here's the relavant portion of my smb.conf**

```
[matt]
comment = Matt
path = /home/matt
public = yes
writable = yes
valid users = matt
create mask = 0771
directory mask = 0771
force user = matt
force group = matt
```

I want the permissions to not be affected at all when saving over the samba connection. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting in smb.conf the [nt acl support](http://optics.ph.unimelb.edu.au/help/samba/smb.conf.5.html#ntaclsupport) to "no" :

> This boolean parameter controls
>   whether smbd will attempt to map UNIX
>   permissions into Windows NT access
>   control lists.
>
> Default: `nt acl support = yes`
>   Example: `nt acl support = no`

Another that might help is :

> [map archive](http://optics.ph.unimelb.edu.au/help/samba/smb.conf.5.html#maparchive) = no

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `(smb.conf) store dos attributes = yes` and `(.vimrc) set backupcopy=yes`

I just spent a few hours testing various options (using VIM 8.1.1 windows 32-bit), here's what I've found:

**samba 3.6.23 x86_64 CentOS 6, ext4 w/extended attrs enabled**

Everything mostly works correctly with all default options, assuming you have `set backup copy = yes` in VIM. `map archive` and `store dos attributes` don't make any difference. Vim's undo, swap and backup files are created with SMB's `create mask`, but the target file's permissions are preserved when overwriting.

The `nt acl support` option seems to break undo files, IF you set VIM's undo dir to some place outside of the Samba share (in Samba 3 only). So I guess it's better to set it to "no" in Samba 3.

**samba 4.4.9 x86_64 CentOS 7, xfs w/extended attrs enabled**

Same as Samba3, but you have to have `store dos attributes` set. However the backup file created by VIM in this configuration seems to always have group permissions set to `rwx`, no matter what I do, I don't know why. I disable VIM backups in my environment anyway, so it doesn't affect me. `nt acl support` doesn't make any difference w.r.t. UNIX permissions in Samba 4.

For completeness, my config files look like this (Samba 4):

#### smb.conf

```sh
    ...
    # Create new files with these permissions. Doesn't affect
    # old files being overwritten by VIM, only the new ones, as well
    # as swap & undo files.
    create mask = 0644

    # Used when creating directories over Samba
    directory mask = 0755

    # Seems to be necessary in Samba 4
    store dos attributes = yes

    # Seems necessary in Samba 3 with some VIM options
    #nt acl support = no
    ...
```

#### .vimrc

```sh
    ...
    # Don't leave backups behind when overwriting files
    set nobackup

    # Create a backup before overwriting a file, but delete it after
    # (makes overwriting files safer in some cases)
    set writebackup

    # When creating a backup, make a copy of the original file, then update
    # the original (this ensures that permissions on the original file
    # remain unchanged)
    set backupcopy=yes
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that neither 'nt acl support = no' nor 'map archive = no' solved the problem.  My experience has been that Samba always applies file permissions defined by 'create mask' and 'directory mask', regardless of whether saving a new or existing file.

Comment: so how would you recommend this problem be fixed?